# Why wordpress inserts my html in one line?

Tags: html, wordpress

When adding a new HTML in `footer.php`, WordPress displays it inline. This creates problems when there are comments. Is there some sort of function against it?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a plugin or setting that's 'minifying' the HTML (removing spaces and line breaks to save file space). Maybe a plugin like this one https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/minify-html-markup/. I'm not that familiar with WP but that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: Did you mean you have edit `footer.php` then wordpress create all `footer.php` code in one line right?

Comment: @purvik7373 right

Comment: @ArtemDrobizov Are you using FileZilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem was with **Filezilla FTP client default transfer mode**, by default it is **"Auto"**. Follow below step to convert it into **"binary"**.

Go to the **"Edit | Settings… "**

[image]

In new window, go to **"transfers | File Types "** and in ***"Default transfer type"***, select **"Binary"**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a line of text to break into two or more lines. You've got a few options.

1. Give your element, e.g. div, a width property in CSS. Reduce the width until the line is the desired length.

   ```
   p {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 1em;
     width: 50%;
   }
   ```
2. If you're using a WYSIWYG field, you may be able to add 
    tags, or line breaks to force the lines to break where you wish them to.
3. If you're writing HTML you can literally throw a `<br>` tag into a line of text, a `<p>` tag for example, and it will start a new line directly after the line break tag.

Comment: No, I'm talking about "<footer class="footer-primary edge"><div class="container"><div class="wrapper"><p></p></div></div></footer><!-- footer-primary --></body></html>"

Comment: i can add \n after each line. "<footer class="footer-primary edge"><?php echo '\n' ?>" but I think it's stupid.

Comment: @ArtemDrobizov Then I think you need to give your `<p>` a display property of block or inline-block. That will force other elements to create space for it. From there you can add padding or margin to give it even more room. I've edited my answer for demonstration purposes.